# How to use token cache file after app is reopened?

Tags: c#, wpf, access-token, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm a rookie for Microsoft Identity Client development.

My expectation would be that the first login executes the interactive authentication with AcquireTokenInteractive function and then there is no need to login again with AcquireTokenSilent function. It works when the app executed. But when I close the app without signing out and reopen it, I need to login with interactive authentication. AcquireTokenSilent returns nothing in cache.
I already use cacheHelper to register cached and it generate a dat file.

How to let AcquireTokenSilent read the cache file after the app is reopened or I just misunderstood about the token cache? thanks

My .Net script as below:

```
 public static async Task<string> GetTokenForUserAsync()  //SignIn Web Page
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult;
        var accounts = await IdentityClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
        try
        {
            authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(Scopes, accounts.First()).ExecuteAsync();
            TokenForUser = authResult.AccessToken;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (TokenForUser == null || Expiration <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5))
            {
                authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes).ExecuteAsync();

                TokenForUser = authResult.AccessToken;
                Expiration = authResult.ExpiresOn;
            }
        }
        var storageProperties = new StorageCreationPropertiesBuilder("msal_cache.dat", "MSAL_CACHE").Build();
        var cacheHelper = await MsalCacheHelper.CreateAsync(storageProperties);
        cacheHelper.RegisterCache(IdentityClientApp.UserTokenCache);
        return TokenForUser;
    }
```

Comment: I think you should register the cache before acquiring tokens. Can you do it immediately after you create the `IdentityClientApp`?

Comment: Seems like it's work.  Although I don't know why  but very thanks

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Yes it works. But I have another question. I use this codes as below to  get token

authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;


But it will not display a window to let use login.  and just not any response